# How to limit image upload size TinyMCE RoR

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE for Rails and cannot find how to limit image upload size.
Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom validator in your model. For example:

```
validate :image_size_validation, :if => "!image.blank?"  

  def image_size_validation
    errors[:image] << "should be less than 1MB" if image.size > 1.megabytes
  end
```